# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Does Not Show Items

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-5

My bootstrap navbar dropdown does this when I put it in my custom navbar. Any idea as to why and how to fix the problem?
The Image below shows the problem. I can't see the items on the dropdown menu unless I hover my mouse over, and the text is blue. I also don't want the text to be blue when I hover.

[image]

I have looked online and tried removing bootstrap css for only that element.
Here is the code for the css and html, as well as some php.

```css
        .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .top-navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 40px;
  }

  .top-navbar-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .top-menu {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .top-menu li {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .top-menu li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .top-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .main-navbar {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  .main-navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .logo-container {
    width: 80px;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .menu-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .menu {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .menu li {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .menu li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .icons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  .cart-icon {
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .logo-container {
  width: 78px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <nav class="top-navbar">
        <div class="top-navbar-container">
            <ul class="top-menu">

                
                <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['auth']))
        {
            ?> 
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <?= $_SESSION['auth_user']['name'] ?>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            

            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
 <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
        </li>
        
            <?php
        }
        ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="icons">
                <a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping fa-xl" style="color: #0000ff;"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="main-navbar">
        <div class="main-navbar-container">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="Noah Grocery Logo.png" alt="Grocery Store Logo" class="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="menu-container">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="support/support.html">Support</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The code snippet doesn't have bootstrap connected to that page. Bootstrap is in a different file on my site.

Comment: We can't fix pictures alone (unsurprisingly). Please add a [mre] of the issue to your question. See also [ask]. Also this is probably a HTML & CSS issue, not PHP. Consider re-tagging

Comment: Also i think css prefers to be element.classname .. so like instead of being like H1 is class .h1class you would use this h1.classname .. you need a selector for the element i think.  so its like li.nav-item not just .nav-item when you put it the css code.

Comment: I do not understand. Maybe you could send a version of the code with your edits? Thanks!

Comment: Example this ->
  .top-navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 40px;
  }
is actually this ->
  div.top-navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 40px;
  }

Comment: name the element and then the class ... li.classname not just .classname

Comment: That did not work

Comment: That did not work either. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Every css element would need to be fixed for it to even attempt to work.  Otherwise it doesn't know which element and ignores it.  if you are SURE your code is correct inistead put it INLINE so be like style ="csscode;" and see if the look changes, then you know the code is right its just the way you are calling it might not link up.

Comment: <li class="nav-item"> wait a tick .. was going to use that as an example of how to style="css" then i didn't find it in your css code ...  is .nav_item in there?

Comment: I am just not sure because I am pretty sure it is bootstrap that is making the text color blue on hover and hiding the items unless you hover. None of the suggestions are working.

Comment: I am talking about my bootstrap, there is no css for the dropdown menu

Comment: Well to over ride that you would make an on hover version of the css element.  h1.h1css{};  for a blank h1ss style .. then you make an on hover version like this h1.h1css:OnHover{  what to do when it hovers this element  }  and if that still doesnt work add !important to the end of the css line that is required.

Comment: I am confused. The dropdown has no css styling other than the bootstrap. It is a ul element and li that cause the problem.

Comment: Would there be any way to just remove bootstrap CSS from only the dropdown and li elements?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's because you are using the `dark navbar` but made it custom and you made the `<li>` color to be `white` so either you can use the bootstrap's dark navbar:

for that you can use add `data-bs-theme="dark"` like this `<nav class="top-navbar" data-bs-theme="dark">`

or if want to go with your custom navbar you can style your `<li>` font-color to be dark:

```
.top-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    /* color: #fff; */
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand. I made my own navbar, not using any bootstrap. I tried your suggestion, but it did not work still.

Comment: @RandomCoder16 ok so just change the css which i gave ...you set the font-color to be #fff in your css so it matches the background color that's why it is not visible

Comment: What do you mean? How would I change it?

Comment: in your css file change the font color of the li for the top-menu